# How to generate OAuth2.0 Bearer when calling App Engine Endpoints API?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I am providing a REST API via App Engine. I used Cloud Endpoints to generate it, although the client will not be mobile Android/iPhone but rather a known web server. Since I am familiar with this server (it is part of my application), I decided to use Service Account authorization in order to authorize the API calls (In addition, I will do IP validation, but that's beside the point).

I made all the necessary arrangement, created a Google developer project, generated a service account id (and email), with a p12 file, and added all the annotations needed on the server side (including a User object in the implementing function).

Now I want to implement a call to this API, and in order for it to work, I need to include a proper authorization header in my request.

When working with Google APIs, the client libraries generate some Credential object which you later need to pass in building some Service object, which represents a Google API you wish to call. For example, if you want to access Drive API in Java, you will do:

Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(Globals.httpTransport, Globals.jsonFactory, credential).build();

Where credential object is the object I previously build as follows:

credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(Globals.httpTransport)
.setJsonFactory(Globals.jsonFactory)
.setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
.setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
.setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file(serviceAccountPrivateKeyP12File))
.build();

However, in my case, the client is not calling a Google API, but rather my App Engine REST API. How do I go about generating (or using the credential object I created to obtain) a proper Authorization header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some documentation in the readme.html file that is generated alongside the bindings, and [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).

You can get the following account information in the [console](https://console.developers.google.com/), "Apis & Auth", "Credentials". Here you need to paste "Email Address" of the service account. Your @Api annotation should include the account's "Client Id" in the "clientIds" parameter.

```
String accountEmail = "your-service-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
String keyFilePath = "your-key-file.p12";
```

This is the minimum authorization scope that is required for Cloud Endpoints API. It only allows the app to access the user's e-mail address. Your @Api annotation should list it in the "scopes" parameter.

```
String emailScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
```

Then you need to create some support objects and the credential. GsonFactory can be replaced with JsonFactory if you prefer.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GsonFactory gsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(gsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(accountEmail)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(emailScope))
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(keyFilePath))
    .build();
```

And finally create your API client. Replace YourApi with the client from the generated bindings. If you want to test against the dev AppServer, you can call .setRootUrl(yourDevServerUrl + "/_ah/api") on the builder.

```
YourApi client = new YourApi.Builder(httpTransport, gsonFactory, credential)
   .setApplicationName("YourClientName")
   .build();
```

Comment: Hey Ivan, will take a look in couple of days. Thanks!

Comment: Any similar examples for the python client library? I'm trying to pass my authorizations from a local python script (using service account) to my app engine endpoints API, and I'm just having no luck.

Comment: I have done this, my api methor executes,  but I have not a way to know if authorization has occurred because the User object is null. Dou you experiment the same? 

`@ApiMethod(path = "hellomachine", name = "helloMachine", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
 public TestMessage helloMachine(final User user) {
  
  if (user == null)
   return new TestMessage("Unknown user");
  else
   return new TestMessage("Hello " + user.getEmail());
 }
`